# using SSL without certificate

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl

I am trying to use SSL without any certificate. I've read that it is possible so I am writing code without the calls to set it.
According to the documentation it should be the right list of steps.
Do you know if that is really possible?

I am using CENTOS 6.4.

When I run I always receive error

```
 14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Below is my code for the Server

```
  int main() {
    int res = -1;
    SSL_library_init();       
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    SSL_CTX *sslctx = SSL_CTX_new( SSLv23_server_method());

    res = SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(sslctx,"aNULL");
    if(0 == res) {
        cerr << "SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list" << endl;
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }



    int res = -1;

    sockaddr_in addr;
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port   = htons(kPort);
    memset(&addr.sin_zero,0,8);

    int sfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sfd == -1) {
      cerr << "Socket Failed" << endl;
      std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    res = bind(sfd, (const sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    if(res == -1) {
      cerr << "Bind Failed" << endl;
      std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    res = listen(sfd,kBackLog);
    if(res == -1) {
      cerr << "Listen Failed" << endl;
      std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    sockaddr_in client_addr;
    socklen_t   client_addr_len;
    int cfd = accept(sfd, (sockaddr*)&client_addr, &client_addr_len);
    if(cfd == -1) {
      cerr << "Accept Failed" << endl;
      std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cout << "Client Connected" << endl;

    // new SSL context.
    SSL *cSSL = SSL_new(sslctx);
    res = SSL_set_fd(cSSL, cfd);
    cout << res << endl;
    if(0 == res) {
      cerr << "Error on SSL_set_fd" << endl;
      close(sfd);
      std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    res = SSL_set_cipher_list(cSSL, "aNULL");
    if(0 == res) {
        cout << "failure on SSL_set_cipher_list";
        close(sfd);
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }



    //Here is the SSL Accept portion.  Now all reads and writes must use SSL
    cout << "call to SSL_accept" << endl;
    res = SSL_accept(cSSL);
    switch(res)
    {
      case 0:
      case -1: {
      cout << "error on SSL_accept("<< res << ")" << endl;
      std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    }

    char buf[4];
    res = SSL_read(cSSL, (char*)buf, 4);
    switch(res) {
      case  0:
      case -1: {
      cout << "error on SSL_read("<< res << ")" << endl;
      std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }  
    } 
    cout << buf << endl;  
  }
```

And below the one for the client

```
    int main() {
      int res = -1;
      SSL_library_init();       
      SSL_load_error_strings();
      //OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms(); I didn't find this in man pages.
      SSL_CTX *sslctx = SSL_CTX_new( SSLv23_client_method());


      res = SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(sslctx,"aNULL");
      if(0 == res) {
        cerr << "SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list" << endl;
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      int res = -1;
      int sfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
      CHECK(sfd,"socket");

      struct sockaddr_in addr;
      addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
      addr.sin_port        = htons(kPort); 
      addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); // #include <arpa/inet.h>

      res = connect(sfd, (const sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
      CHECK(res, "connect");
      if(-1 == res) {
        cerr << "Error on Connect" << endl;
        close(sfd);
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      SSL *cSSL = SSL_new(sslctx);
      if(NULL == cSSL) {
        cerr << "Error on SSL_new" << endl;
        close(sfd);
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      res = SSL_set_fd(cSSL, sfd);
      if(0 == res) {
        cerr << "Error on SSL_set_fd" << endl;
        close(sfd);
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      res = SSL_set_cipher_list(cSSL, "aNULL");
      if(0 == res) {
        cout << "failure on SSL_set_cipher_list";
        close(sfd);
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      cout << "calling SSL connect" << endl;
      res = SSL_connect(cSSL);    
      switch(res) {
        case 0:
        case -1: {
         cerr << "Error on SSL_connect("<< res << ")" << endl;
         print_ssl_error(cSSL, res);
         close(sfd);
         std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }
      }

      cout << "SSL write" << endl;
      char buf[4] = {'a','b','c','\n'};
      SSL_write(cSSL, buf, 4);

      sleep(10);
      close(sfd);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to use SSL without any certificate.

You need to use Anonymous Diffie-Hellman (ADH) or Anonymous Elliptic Curve Diffie Hellman (AECDH). When using anonymous schemes, the server does not send its certificate.

Call [`SSL_set_cipher_list`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list.html) before `SSL_connect`. According to [`ciphers(1)`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html), the cipher you want is `aNULL`. `aNULL` includes both `ADH` and `AECDH`.

---

> Do you know if that is really possible?

Yes, its possible. But its a bad idea to use anonymous cipher suites because they are prone to active attacks. That is, they can be Man-in-the-Middle'd.

Also, most clients and servers are configured to *reject* anonymous cipher suites via `"!aNULL"` cipher suite list. So you might find in practice that you can't really connect to anything.

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot but unfortunately it doesn't work. I just put only in the client the call to  'SSL_set_cipher_list(cSSL, "aNULL")' but the error is always there.

Comment: P.S. I put the whole error message I get in case it might help.

Comment: @Abruzzo - I don't see where the client or the server are calling `SSL_set_cipher_list` (client) or `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list` (server). The handshake alert occurs when the client and server *cannot* agree on a shared cipher. Both the client and server need to enable the ADH/AECDH because they are disabled by default. And be sure to check the return value from `SSL_{CTX}_set_cipher_list` to ensure CentOS does not disable it. If its disabled, then you will need to build your own version of OpenSSL.

Comment: I've just added it to the main code. I've added also SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list but it doesn't work.

Comment: We need to see some Wireshark traces. Both the `ClientHello` and the `ServerHello`.

Comment: Hi I have just recorded some wireshark and aside from establishing the TCP/IP communication,   I cannot see anything else. How to post the wireshark capture?

Comment: Snap a couple of screen captures. One for the `ClientHello`, and one for the `ServerHello`. For example: [Wireshark Capture](http://postimg.org/image/xyzahygmf/). Once you take a couple, add them to your question.

Comment: ok, but just to reiterate there is NO ClientHello or ServerHallo in the capture. I don't have any packets with TLS or SSL protocol produced...no ClientHello, No ServerHello..

Comment: Hi jvw. I have probably found a silly thing that might deal with this problem. IN the code above I am not checking the return value of SSL_CTX_new; today I fond that it returns NULL because of error 'library has no ciphers'..

Comment: @AbruzzoForteeGentile - It sounds liek you did not initialize the library. See [Library Initialization](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Library_Initialization) on the OpenSSL wiki.